# jquery slider that allows image upload in wp backend

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jquery slider that will allow me to upload images in the WP backend rather than change images in the actual code (like NIVO). I know there are sliders for post images. All I want is to have a slider on my homepage that I can update by adding new images and links in the WordPress backend and not have to deal with any code changes. Is there such a plugin, tutorial on how to write one or a suggestion on how to modify something to fit my needs?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The two things you are differentiating are one and the same. In order to use images uploaded from the WP backend, you *need* to be able to, as you put it, change the images in the actual code. So you can use any jQuery plugin to use the Wordpress backend to add images.

If you are comfortable modifying WordPress theme templates and styling with CSS, you can use Magic Fields ( http://magicfields.org/ ) to create duplicate fields which will allow you to add multiple images. Then you can populate those images in your template using the following code inside the loop:

```
<ul>
<?php 
$things = get_order_group('slide_img');
foreach($things as $thing) {
?>
     <li><img src="<?php echo get('slide_img',$thing); ?>"></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The majority of jQuery slideshow plugins use this HTML structure of unordered lists.

If not, you could give this a try: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easing-slider/